# Linux RFID reader HID Device not matching driver

Tags: linux, usb, driver, hid, rfid

I got a RFID reader (GigaTek PCR330A-00) that is meant to be recognized under linux/windows as a (Human Interface Device) keyboard/USB.

I hate to say this but it is working as a charm under Win7 but not "really" under Linux.

Under Debian-like distros (x/k/Ubuntu, Debian,..), or Gentoo, or... I just can't have the device working at all: the device scan well (it has its USB 5V, so it is happy/beeping/blinking) something happened in the dmesg, but no immediate screen display of the RFID Tag code as expected (and seen under win7)

Support is claiming it is ok under RHEL or SLED "enterprises" distros... and I must admit I saw it working under a RHEL4... I tried stealing the driver but did not succeed having my reader working...

My question is thus double:
1./ How can I hack the kernel to add support to my device (simply register PID/VID?) ?
2./ What is different at all in a "enterprise" proprietary distro? how can I re-use it?

Thank you for any hint/help.

Cheers,

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean, it's quite cryptic or it sounds like spam?!

Comment: OK, got, sorry for mis-posting..

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code of the driver you can compile it against the current Kernel your system uses, since the Kernel only allows drivers for its current version. Then you can  try to load it as a Kernel module, notice that by doing this, you do not hack the Kernel you just need your current system's Kernel header to compile the driver against it.

You may want to check this http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux in order to grasp the basics.

Hope this helps.